# how do functions work in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a simple function called Range that creates an array of integers based on start, step and end value...

```
function Range (start, end, step) {

  // default step is 1..
  if (step === undefined ) step = 1;

  // creating an array...
  var arr = [], index = 0;

  while(start <= end) {
  arr[index]  = start ;
  index += 1;
  start += step; 
  }

  // simple function expressions
  var getAll = function () {
    return arr  ;  
  };

  var getOne = function(n) {
    return arr[n] ;
  };


  // returns a unnamed function ..
  return function(i) { 
    if (i === undefined) { return getAll() ;}
    else {return getOne(i); } 
  };  // not an iife

}
```

so basically *Range* is a function which returns a unnamed function which again returns a named function expression declared in the function *Range*.. err.. i dont know.. something like that...

now the below code...

```
var first10 = Range (1,10) ; // no new ..() here, so no instance should be created.. only Range is called..
var first10Odd = Range(1,20,2) ; // and Range is called again..

alert(first10); // alerts - function(i) { ... }
alert(first10Odd); // alerts- function(i) { ... } 

alert(first10()) ; // alerts - 1,2,3,...10
alert(first10Odd()); // alerts - 1,3,5,...19

alert(first10(0)); // alerts - 1 
alert(first10Odd(9)); // alerts- 19
```

why do the alerts alert as specified in the comments??... i think *Range* is a just a function and not a object constructor and also no instance was created... shouldn't the local variables of function be destroyed as soon as the function is completed??
or is my logic wrong?? what is going on in the above code?? can anyone please explain....

[i have made a fiddle of my code here..](http://jsfiddle.net/j9zNW/)

sorry for asking this stupid question..

Comment: Re: lines 3/4 - functions *are* objects. If you don't invoke them with `.call`, `.apply` or `()` they are simply the function-objects themselves.

Comment: Read on "closures", "scope" and "first class functions".

Comment: Also, constructors that return functions (or, rather, constructors that return anything but `this`) are no longer constructors; they're just functions (a bit of a gross simplification, but hopefully conveys the point)

Comment: You need to read about closures in javascript.  The local variables of `Range()` are still in scope of the returned anonymous function so they live on as long as there is a reference to the internal anonymous function.  This construct is called a closure and the way garbage collection works in javascript, that closure is kept alive as long as there are references to things in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the land of closures in Javascript.  They can be very powerful and extremely useful once you understand them.  But, if your prior experience is with languages that do not have them, they can feel a bit foreign at first.

Some answers/explanation:

1. Calling `Range(x, y)` returns a function that can then be called later.
2. Because that function that is returned is inside another function scope that has variables, a closure is created.
3. That closure stays alive (even though the outer function has finished executing) because there is a lasting reference to the inner function saved in your variables and that inner function has a reference to the local variables in the outer function.  These references keep the closure from being garbage collected (so it stays alive).
4. That inner function can then reference the variables in the outer function, including the arguments originally passed to it.
5. This construct allows you to create these custom functions that have arguments pre-built into them.
6. The notion of this type of closure only exists in some languages.  It does not exist in C++, for example.
7. When the function returned by calling Range(x,y) is itself executed later, it can use any of the variables that were originally in scope to it.
8. Each call to `Range(x,y)` causes a new closure to be created.
9. `getAll` and `getOne` are local variables in the outer function that are assigned a function.  They access other local variables in the outer function.  All of these are in the previously mentioned closure that is created each time `Range()` is called.

There is lots written about what a closure is (which you can Google and read), but I like to think of it as an execution context that contains everything that was in scope at the time a function is called (including all variables).   Each time a function is called, such an execution context it created.  Since everything in javascript is garbage collected and will only be freed/destroyed when there are no references left to it, this is true for this execution context too (e.g. closure).  As long as something has a reference to it or something in it, then the execution context will stay alive and can be used by any code that might run into that execution context.

---

Line by line annotation:

```
// first10 is assigned the anonymous function that the call to Range()
// returned.  That anonymous function has access to the original arguments
// passed to the Range(1,10) call and other local variables in that function.
var first10 = Range (1,10) ; // no new ..() here, so no instance should be created.. only Range is called..

// same as the call before, except this also includes the step argument
var first10Odd = Range(1,20,2) ; // and Range is called again..

// this makes sense because Range(1,10) returns a function so
// when you alert it's value, it tells you it's a function
alert(first10); // alerts - function(i) { ... }
alert(first10Odd); // alerts- function(i) { ... } 

// When you execute the function in first10, it runs that function 
// and the alert shows the return value from that function
// This particular function is set to return the entire array if nothing is passed
// to it
alert(first10()) ; // alerts - 1,2,3,...10
alert(first10Odd()); // alerts - 1,3,5,...19


// This particular function is set to return a specific index from the array
// if an argument is passed to it
alert(first10(0)); // alerts - 1 
alert(first10Odd(9)); // alerts- 19
```

If you know how to use the javascript debugger, you can set a breakpoint on this line `if (i === undefined) { return getAll() ;}` in the inner function and you will be able to inspect all the variables that are in scope, including `start`, `end` and `step` from the outer function.

---

You may find this article useful reading as it encapsulates some of the ways that closures can be used with object declarations: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html (not exactly what is being done here, but might help you understand them).

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - closures aren't a simple concept to grasp the first time so I thought I'd try to be thorough.

Comment: i'm only learning javascript.. and without even knowing about closures in javascript.. i'm already starting to use them.. how funny.. :D and thanks for your clarification...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to javascript closures. Lets take line by line.

```
var first10 = Range(1,10);
var first10Odd = Range(1,20,2);
```

We know that `Range` is just a function. So, in these two lines we are just calling `Range` function with 2 and 3 arguments respectively.

Now, what happens when you call a function. The obvious answer is, the body of the function gets executed. What do we have in the body of the function.

```
if (step === undefined ) step = 1;

var arr = [], index = 0;

while(start <= end) {
  arr[index]  = start ;
  index += 1;
  start += step; 
}
```

I hope that the above seen lines are pretty obvious and you don't have any problems with them.

```
var getAll = function () {
   return arr;
};
```

What does this line do? It creates a function at run time. Why runtime? Lets see an example.

```
<script>
   func1();
   var func1 = function() {
      alert("Hi");
   }
</script>

<script>
   func1();
   function func1() {
      alert("Hi");
   }
</script>
```

If you use the first script block, it will throw error. Why? You are calling a function which hasn't been defined yet. The second case, you are defining the function during javascript parsing time itself. The type of function which was created in the first case is called **anonymous function**. Let us get back to `getAll`. Now we know that `getAll` is simply a variable which points to an anonymous function, lets look at what it does. It returns `arr`. How does it have access to `arr`? It is declared outside the function and so it still has access to it. Same case with

```
var getOne = function(n) {
  return arr[n] ;
};
```

Now the very important part,

```
  return function(i) { 
    if (i === undefined) {
       return getAll();
    } else {
       return getOne(i);
    }
  };
```

What does it do? It returns a function. To be precise, it returns an anonymous function. Whenever `Range` is called, it creates a new anonymous function, which accepts one parameter and returns it. So, now what do `first10` and `first10Odd` have? Yes. You are right, they have functions. I hope that explains

```
alert(first10);    // alerts - function(i) { ... }
alert(first10Odd); // alerts - function(i) { ... }
```

Let us examine both the functions. When `first10` is called with nothing, I mean, `first10()`, the parameter `i` takes the value `undefined`. So, we are actually making a call to the anonymous function with no parameters and it is supposed to return `getAll()`. If you remember, `first10` was created with `Range(1,10);`. So, the `arr` will now have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

You might ask, when we return from the function, wont the variables declared inside the function go out of scope. The answer is Yes and No. Yes, when you simply return a value. No, when you return a function. When you return a function, the state of the variables will be maintained. This property is called `closures`. That is why it returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]     for alert(first10())
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19] for alert(first10Odd())
1                                   for alert(first10(0))
19                                  for alert(first10Odd(9))
```

Please read more about Closure here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: just learning javascript.. and without even knowing what closures are in javascript.. i'm already using them.. funny.. and thanks for your clarification...